# Bet365.com site not loading with selenium in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to open [bet365.com](https://www.bet365.com/#/HO/) successfully using selenium in python

But the issue that I am facing is that when i use driver.get to open bet365 the loader keeps on moving i have tried different options in selenium webdriver and i have even tried proxies but nothing is working Check out what i have tried so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
profile = "C:\\Users\\Faiq-81-LP\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1"
options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={profile}")
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.bet365.com")
time.sleep(14)
```

If someone can give his view on what should i do next that can open this site successfully in selenium and i have also tried undetected chromedriver it also did not work

Comment: Why are you using all those options?  Why not just open the site normally with webdriver?

Comment: it is not opening normally the loader keeps on loading without those options as well

Answer (score 0):

You must install Chromedriver with the exact version as your Chrome browser is installed.

Your code is independent of the Chromedriver.

I was able to open it with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bet365.com")
```

Comment: this code does not work i already tried when the website opens up using selenium there is loader in place that keeps on moving